# Rails - how to show two attributes in a collection select form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection_select form with the following code:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:city_id,  City.order('name ASC'),  :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a City"}, {:id => 'cities_select'}) %>
```

Right now it just lists all of the cities by name in my database, but there are duplicate city names. For example, there are two "Peoria" cities.

So, I want to show the state attribute separate by a comma like: "Peoria, IL" to help distinguish the cities. How do I write this code within the form code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use `collection_select` for that

```
f.collection_select :city_id, City.order('name ASC'), :id, :name_with_state, { prompt: 'Select a City' }, { id: 'cities_select' }
```

`name_with_state` should be in your city model

```
def name_with_state
  "#{name}, #{state}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f.select :city_id, City.all.map{|c| ["#{c.name}, #{c.state}", c.id] }, { :prompt => "Select City" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use select:

```
<%= f.select(:city_id,  City.order('name ASC').map{ |city| [city.your_method, city.id]},
      {:prompt   => "Select a City"}, {:id => 'cities_select'}) %>
```